# Creating API backend on App Engine

Tags: google-app-engine, go

I would like to create a rest backend for an application on App Engine using Go.

I have arranged my files as fallow:

```
-> app/
   -> auth/
     -> auth.go
   -> app.go
   -> app.yaml
```

Normally I would import the auth package in app.go with: `import "github.com/user/app/auth"`, but I get an error saying that there is a conflict between files(I can't paste the error right now).

After looking for a solution on google I've found out that if I remove the github.com... and just `import "auth"` it will work, and it does.

Is the solution above the best fix?

Comment: You can't paste the error -> we can't know what the problem is -> we can't tell if your "fix" is a solution

Comment: Did you update all imports?  Having one pointing to github.com/.../auth and auth will lead to this type of error.

Answer (score 2):

Was the error something like `Failed parsing input: app file auth/auth.go conflicts with same file imported from GOPATH`?

My reading of https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/google-appengine-go/dNhqV6PBqVc/ihzI5vgdE1EJ is that it's now better to arrange your files so that you can use the `github.com/user/...` import. This is due to new behavior with SDK 1.9.1 that breaks some project layouts. Using `import "auth"` will mostly work, but it breaks `goapp test` and may cause other problems.

Instead the idea is to make sure that there isn't any other go code at or under the level of your `app.yaml` and `app.go`. To do this you could move `auth` up two levels, to the parent of `app`, and import it as `github.com/user/auth`. That would make sense if you might use that same code in other apps.

```
-> app/
   -> app.go
   -> app.yaml
-> auth/
   -> auth.go
```

Or move `auth` up one level, and move the yaml and `app.go` into a subdirectory. If you do that you'll have to cd into that directory to run `goapp server`, because that's where the `app.yaml` is.

```
-> app/
   -> auth/
      -> auth.go
   -> app/
      -> app.go
      -> app.yaml
```

Either way, there should be only one `*.go` file in the same directory as the `app.yaml`.